# Convert working SQL Script to work with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I put together the following code to import multiple csv files and split the imported data into various tables in SQL 2014. I would like to do the same but using PostgreSQL instead. (I want to use PostgreSQL instead of SQL Server)

Is this possible?

The csv files contain sales data for various products by store, region, catergories etc, by period.

I need to keep a list of the imported csv files so as not to import them again as this code will run every month importing new data

```
    --BULK INSERT MULTIPLE FILES From a Folder 
    USE DynamicBrands
    --a table to loop thru filenames drop table ALLFILENAMES
    CREATE TABLE ALLFILENAMES(WHICHPATH VARCHAR(255),WHICHFILE varchar(255))

    --some variables
    declare @filename varchar(255),
    @TransactionsOnlyFF varchar(255),
    @tmpImportedDataFF varchar(255),
    @filenameFF varchar(255),
    @@ImportERRORS varchar(255),            
    @path     varchar(255),
    @sql      varchar(8000),
    @StoreCode  varchar(15),
    @PriceRegion    varchar(255),
    @Department varchar(255),
    @Category   varchar(255),
    @SubCategory    varchar(255),
    @Segment    varchar(255),
    @Province   varchar(255),
    @EAN    varchar(15),
    @cmd      varchar(1000),
    @ID_Segment int,
    @ID_SubCategory int,
    @ID_temp int,
    @txtValTemp varchar(255)
    --get the list of files to process:
    SET @path = 'c:\dump\'
    SET @TransactionsOnlyFF = 'ImportTransFormat.txt'
    SET @tmpImportedDataFF = 'tmpImportedDataFF.txt'
    SET @@ImportERRORS = 'ImportTransErrors'
    SET @cmd = 'dir ' + @path + '*.csv /b'

    INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES(WHICHFILE)
    EXEC Master..xp_cmdShell @cmd
    UPDATE ALLFILENAMES SET WHICHPATH = @path where WHICHPATH is null
    delete from ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE is NULL


    --cursor loop
    declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES where                 WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
    open c1

    fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename

    While @@fetch_status <> -1

    BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT WHICHFILE FROM IMPORTEDFILENAMES WHERE WHICHFILE = @filename)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IMPORTEDFILENAMES(WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE)
                        Values(@path, @filename)
                        --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
                                       set @sql = 'BULK INSERT dbo.[TransactionsOnly] FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
                                           + '     WITH ( 
                                                   FORMATFILE = ''' + @path + @TransactionsOnlyFF + ''',
                                                   FIRSTROW = 2,
                                                   TABLOCK
                                                   ) '
                                    --print @sql
                                    exec (@sql)

                                    --print 'Importing file ' +  @filename



                        --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
                                       set @sql = 'BULK INSERT dbo.[tmpImportedData] FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
                                           + '     WITH ( 
                                                   FORMATFILE = ''' + @path + @tmpImportedDataFF + ''',
                                                   FIRSTROW = 2,
                                                   TABLOCK
                                                   ) '
                                    --print @sql
                                    exec (@sql)         

                        --We have all the data in a tmp Table
                        -- LOOP through tmp Table and Check if Store AND OR Product Exists and add them if they dont
                        declare getTmpStoreData cursor for SELECT StoreCode FROM tmpImportedData GROUP BY StoreCode
                        open getTmpStoreData
                        fetch next from getTmpStoreData into @StoreCode


                                While @@fetch_status <> -1
                                BEGIN

                                                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT StoreCode FROM StoreDetails WHERE StoreCode = @StoreCode)
                                                BEGIN
                                                --Check if PriceRegion exists in table. if not add it and store FK in @PriceRegion
                                                SELECT @StoreCode = StoreCode, @Province = Province, @PriceRegion =PriceRegion 
                                                FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                WHERE StoreCode = @StoreCode

                                                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT PriceRegion FROM PriceRegion WHERE PriceRegion LIKE @PriceRegion)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.PriceRegion
                                                      (PriceRegion)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) PriceRegion
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE StoreCode = @StoreCode
                                                     SELECT @ID_temp = ID_PriceRegion,  @txtValTemp = PriceRegion FROM PriceRegion WHERE PriceRegion LIKE @PriceRegion
                                                    Set @PriceRegion = @ID_temp
                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT @ID_temp = ID_PriceRegion,  @txtValTemp = PriceRegion FROM PriceRegion WHERE PriceRegion LIKE @PriceRegion
                                                    Set @PriceRegion = @ID_temp
                                                    END
                                                --Check if province exists in table. if not add it and store FK in @Province
                                                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Province FROM Province WHERE Province LIKE @Province)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.Province
                                                      (Province)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) Province
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE StoreCode = @StoreCode
                                                     SELECT  @ID_temp =ID_Province, @txtValTemp = Province FROM Province WHERE Province LIKE @Province
                                                    Set @Province = @ID_temp
                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT  @ID_temp =ID_Province, @txtValTemp = Province FROM Province WHERE Province LIKE @Province
                                                    Set @Province = @ID_temp
                                                    END

                                                INSERT INTO dbo.StoreDetails
                                                  (Storename, StoreCode, Province, PriceRegion)
                                                SELECT TOP(1) Storename, StoreCode, @Province, @PriceRegion
                                                  FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                 WHERE StoreCode = @StoreCode

                                                END
                                                --ELSE
                                                --BEGIN
                                                --print 'Store Exists'
                                                --END

                                fetch next from getTmpStoreData into @StoreCode
                                END -- End innermost WHile

                        declare getTmpProductData cursor for SELECT EAN FROM tmpImportedData GROUP BY EAN
                        open getTmpProductData
                        fetch next from getTmpProductData into @EAN


                                While @@fetch_status <> -1
                                BEGIN                           

                                                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT EAN FROM ProductDetails WHERE EAN = @EAN)
                                                BEGIN
                                                --Check if Department exists in table. if not add it and store FK in @Department
                                                SELECT @EAN = EAN, @Department = Department, @Category = Category , @SubCategory = SubCategory, @Segment = Segment
                                                FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                WHERE EAN = @EAN
                                                IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Department FROM Department WHERE Department LIKE @Department)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.Department
                                                      (Department)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) Department
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE  EAN = @EAN
                                                     SELECT @ID_temp = ID_Department, @txtValTemp = Department FROM Department WHERE Department LIKE @Department
                                                    Set @Department = @ID_temp
                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT @ID_temp = ID_Department, @txtValTemp = Department FROM Department WHERE Department LIKE @Department
                                                    Set @Department = @ID_temp
                                                    END

                                                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Category FROM Category WHERE Category LIKE @Category)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.Category
                                                      (Category)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) Category
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE  EAN = @EAN
                                                     SELECT @ID_temp = ID_Category, @txtValTemp = Category FROM Category WHERE Category LIKE @Category
                                                    Set @Category = @ID_temp
                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT @ID_temp = ID_Category, @txtValTemp = Category FROM Category WHERE Category LIKE @Category
                                                    Set @Category = @ID_temp
                                                    END

                                                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT SubCategory FROM SubCategory WHERE SubCategory LIKE @SubCategory)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.SubCategory
                                                      (SubCategory)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) SubCategory
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE  EAN = @EAN
                                                     SELECT @ID_SubCategory = ID_SubCategory, @txtValTemp = SubCategory FROM SubCategory WHERE SubCategory LIKE @SubCategory

                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT @ID_SubCategory = ID_SubCategory, @txtValTemp = SubCategory FROM SubCategory WHERE SubCategory LIKE @SubCategory
                                                    END

                                                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID_Segment ,Segment FROM Segment WHERE Segment LIKE @Segment)
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    INSERT INTO dbo.Segment
                                                      (Segment)
                                                    SELECT TOP(1) Segment
                                                      FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                     WHERE  EAN = @EAN
                                                     SELECT  @ID_Segment = ID_Segment, @txtValTemp = Segment FROM Segment WHERE Segment LIKE @Segment

                                                    END
                                                    ELSE
                                                    BEGIN
                                                    SELECT  @ID_Segment = ID_Segment, @txtValTemp = Segment FROM Segment WHERE Segment LIKE @Segment

                                                    END

                                                INSERT INTO dbo.ProductDetails
                                                  (ProductDesc, EAN, ProductCode, PackType, PacksInCase, UnitsOfMeasure, Department, Category, SubCategory, Segment)
                                                SELECT TOP(1) ProductDesc, EAN, ProductCode, PackType, PacksInCase, UnitsOfMeasure, @Department, @Category,  @ID_SubCategory, @ID_Segment
                                                  FROM dbo.tmpImportedData
                                                 WHERE EAN = @EAN

                                                END
                                                --ELSE
                                                --BEGIN
                                                --print 'Product Exists'
                                                --END
                                fetch next from getTmpProductData into @EAN
                                END -- End innermost WHile

                        --TRUNCATE TmpTables        
                        TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.tmpImportedData
                        close getTmpStoreData
                        deallocate getTmpStoreData  
                        close getTmpProductData
                        deallocate getTmpProductData    
                        END     
                    --ELSE
                    --BEGIN
                    --print 'Allready imported'
                    --END


    fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename

    END --End Outer Most While

    drop table ALLFILENAMES
    close c1
    deallocate c1
```

Comment: Any query writtin in SqlServer can be written in Postgresql. Some will be shorter, some longer, some more complax, some less complax but all is possible. You should start and then ask whatever question you came with.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply and encouraging answer (all is possible). It was easier than I thought. First time ever working with PostgreSQL.